# Sitecore Page Request Lifecycle

Tags: information-architecture

I was searching for Sitecore `page/request lifecycle` explanation step by step, but didn't find any article that contains full information.

Please help me to get full information on a `Sitecore page lifecycle` where all the events and pipelines are explained and how a URL connects with a Sitecore item and then render all the components?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is too much information to provide in one answer or one article.

I can suggest you to start with this diagram created by [David Morrison](https://twitter.com/dmo_sc)(I have added only few things related to Sitecore Analytics):

[image]

Diagram is actual for Sitecore 7. But in a way, how page is rendered, not too much changed in Sitecore 9. So, it can be good starting point.

Processor and pipeline names are quite descriptive to understand what they do.
To get deep knowledge you can go through them one by one to understand what exact happens inside.

Comment: This diagram is available in every article, explanation is not available.

Comment: @Sandeep I haven't seen description of everything in one article. Setup some .NET Decompiler(IL Spy, dotPeak) + use google and go one by one trough all processor on this diagram. That is how you can get information.

Comment: I think it's important to note that @Gatogordo's answer is still important; many of the common pipelines still execute like httpRequestBegin. The MVC pipeline isn't triggered until TransferMvcLayout/TransferControllerRequest in httpRequestBegin

Answer (score 2):

Martin Davies started an overview of the request pipelines (in SC8) on is blog: http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.be/2015/02/a-sitecore-8-request-from-beginning-to.html

It gives an overview of the pipelines and pipeline steps. Some are already linked to detail pages (still some work to do to get full coverage but that is a lot of work).

I found this article very helpful when I need to figure out where to place a customization in the request process.

More general information on a few commonly used pipelines can also be found on the [CommunityDocs](http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/pipelines-and-events/pipelines/).

MVC specific pipeline information can be found on the [official docs](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/mvc/mvc_and_pipelines).